# OOP php new class creating, how I can do it?

Tags: php, mongodb, class

Why my class takes to me the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW) in file.php on line 6

```
 class mongowork {

    private $mongo = new MongoClient();
    private $db = $mongo->wiki;
    public  $col = $db->articles;

    public function mongocheck($title) {
        $res = $this->$col->find(array('title' => $title));
        if($res->count()>0) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read more OOP php reference material before proceeding. Your code is missing the constructor totally. You cannot declare and assign values to variables in random space inside classes.

```
class mongowork {

  private $mongo;
  private $db;
  public  $col; 

   function __construct() {
      $this->mongo = new MongoClient();
      $this->db = $this->mongo->wiki;
      $this->col = $db->articles;
   }

    public function mongocheck($title) {
       //you wrote $this->$col which is wrong - it should be $this->col
        $res = $this->col->find(array('title' => $title)); 
        if($res->count()>0) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot explain all the concepts here. The above code should work now. But please do start reading up on it. It will really help!

Comment: Thank you, what i must rread about OOP in documentation? Classes and objects?

Comment: You can start with OOPS link here - http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php. If you find that too cryptic to follow at first, just google **"OOPS concepts in PHP"** You will find LOADS of user-friendly tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Properties must be constant values: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

> This declaration may include an initialization, but this
>   initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to
>   be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time
>   information in order to be evaluated.

You should pass the values into or set them in the object's `__construct() method`.